# Youtube not able to play on my django-heroku app. Giving me a mixed content error message

Tags: django, heroku, youtube

I tried to view youtube videos on my app and it didn't work. I checked the console and got this error message

```
    Mixed Content: The page at'https://hispanicheights.herokuapp.com/blog/youtube-video/' 
    was loaded over HTTPS,but requested an insecure script 
    'http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/WQWJdvRx.js'. 
    This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Is there a way around this or is this just the situation until I get a paid account with a domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Heroku, paid plans or not. It is simply that you are linking to an http resource inside a  page that is served by https; since that potentially side steps the man-in-the-middle protection that https gives you, modern browsers forbid it.

The solution is to serve all your dependent scripts via https as well.